# Angular exclude folder from build based on environment variable

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

Created an angular hybrid app that works on browser and desktop. In desktop it's running on webview2 and communicate with native code using messaging. In browser mode it's communicate with server using httpclient. How to exclude desktop implementation code from build when its compiled for web and vice versa?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into schematics (https://angular.io/guide/schematics) in order to template your code based upon your use case.

Comment: You can always alter the `angular.json` file to create new build configurations. In there you can overwrite many things or replace files with others, if that is what you want to do.

Edit: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#alternate-build-configurations